# Proper article use: “le” before “dîner”

Tags: grammaire, articles

What do you want for dinner?
“Que voulez-vous pour le dîner ?” or “Que voulez-vous pour dîner”, without the article "le"?

I have seen it both ways, is one way more correct?

Answer (score 5):

In french the word *Diner* can be used as a noun or a verb like other similar words

> Déjeuner - *le* déjeuner
>
> Souper - *le* souper

In your case your first sentence uses the noun

> Que voulez-vous pour le diner ?

And your second sentence uses the verb

> Que voulez-vous pour diner ?

Both sentences are correct and both mean the same thing

Answer (score 2):

*Dîner* is both a verb and a noun. If you mean *dîner* as a noun, you must add *le*; if you mean *dîner* as a verb, you don't. Both are correct for your sentence. Same for *déjeuner* and *le déjeuner*.